# Why is behavior different between gcc and llvm?

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, gcc, llvm

I'm struggling with compiling some open source libraries, and then I ran into this:

```
GLfloat campos[3] = {0.0 + modelview[2], 0.0 + modelview[6], 0.0 + modelview[10]};
```

This compiles fine on CentOS, using gcc, and I really expected it to.

But then, on the Mac, using XCode with llvm, it won't compile, and I had to change it to:

```
GLfloat campos[3] = static_cast<GLfloat>(0.0 + modelview[2]), static_cast<GLfloat>(0.0 + modelview[6]), static_cast<GLfloat>(0.0 + modelview[10]);
```

And then it worked. For reference, modelview is another GLFloat, like so:

```
GLfloat modelview[16];
```

Since modelview is a GLFloat, the static_cast is being applied to the result of a sum of float with a GLfloat, but I did expect to get this for free.

Why is behavior different?

Comment: It's the sum of a `double` with a `GLfloat`, that's the problem. `0.0` is `double`, `0.0f` is `float`.

Comment: Put "f" after 0.0 as it is interpreted as double in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0.0` is a literal of type `double`, not `float` (ref. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal).
`GLfloat` is typically defined as a `float`.

So, the result of `0.0 + x` (where `x` has type `GLfloat`) is of type `double`.

Assigning a `double` to a `float` is a (potentially) narrowing conversion which is probably what the compiler was complaining about.

You can use `0.0f` (which has type `float`) instead.

Comment: From the link: The suffix type specifier defines the actual type of the floating-point literal:
(no suffix) defines double;
f F defines float;
- I never paid attention to this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @jehuty You'll pick up on these things pretty quickly if you compile your code with -wall. For a while before GLSL supported the f suffix, it used to drive me nuts when I wrote floating-point constants in GLSL using the f suffix (as a habit) and the compiler would spit them back out as a parse error :) But generally speaking in most languages derived from C, you should use an f suffix to denote single-precision floating-point.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the original code is using a C++11 feature. Both GCC and Clang's support for C++11 varies quite a bit between versions. So its entirely possible the version of Clang you're using doesn't have support for that feature.

Comment: Really, what feature is that?

Comment: Actually, it's gcc which is lacking support for a feature in this case, the feature being "narrowing conversions in initialiser lists are an error now."